# Force Plug-n-Play device to use certain driver

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, microphone, rj-45

**Equipment:** Presonus Revelator Microphone

**The Goal**: I would like to use my microphone further away via a USB-To-RJ45 extension. Basically sending USB over an ethernet cord.

**The Problem**: When the microphone is plugged directly into the laptop it works fine. But when I plug it in over the extender I cannot record anything and the computer does not register the device at all. The microphone is receiving power and the computer makes the "connection" noise, but nothing beyond that.

**Device Manager**: I checked the device manager in both scenarios. When plugged in directly I see "Microphone(Revelator)" in "Audio Inputs and Outputs". When connected over the RJ45 I just see "Revelator" under "Unknown Devices" as well as the yellow warning triangle indicating that no driver has been loaded.

**Driver Info**: I used the program USBDeview to gather some in depth information on the device when plugged in using the different connections. Below is a side-by-side comparison.

|  | Plugged Directly | Connected via RJ45 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Device Name | Revelator | Revelator |
| Description | USB Composite Device | Revelator |
| Device Type | Unknown | Vendor Specific |
| Connected | Yes | Yes |
| Safe To Unplug | Yes | No |
| Disabled | No | No |
| USB Hub | No | No |
| Serial Number | JM1C20431589 | JM1C20431589 |
| VendorID | 194f | 194f |
| ProductID | 0d01 | 0d01 |
| Firmware Revision | 1.02 | 1.02 |
| USB Class | 0 | ff |
| USB SubClass | 0 | 0 |
| USB Protocol | 0 | 0 |
| ParentId Prefix | 6&1ea95f5f&0 | 6&1ea95f5f&0 |
| Service Name | usbccgp |  |
| Service Description | @usb.inf,%GenericParent.SvcDesc%;Microsoft USB Generic Parent Driver |  |
| Driver Filename | usbccgp.sys |  |
| Device Mfg |  | (Standard USB Host Controller) |
| Power | 200 mA | 200 mA |
| USB Version | 2 | 2 |
| Driver Description | USB Composite Device |  |
| Driver Version | 10.0.19041.1949 |  |
| Driver InfSection | Composite.Dev.NT |  |
| Driver InfPath | usb.inf |  |
| Instance ID | USB\VID_194F&PID_0D01\JM1C20431589 | USB\VID_194F&PID_0D01\JM1C20431589 |
| Capabilities | "Removable, UniqueID, SurpriseRemovalOK" | "Removable, UniqueID" |

The main difference is that when plugged in directly the microphone is recognized as a composite device (USBDeview also shows several other USB devices being loaded at the same time). When plugged in over RJ45 it is not recognized as such and no driver loads.

**Can other devices connect?**: I have tried the RJ45 connector with a usb drive and a different brand of microphone (Audio-Technica AT2020). In both cases they worked fine and loaded the same drivers. The microphone is especially interesting as it is also a composite device yet has no problems.

**Question**: Is it possible to force my computer to use the same driver in both scenarios? I've been doing some googling but all I can find is stuff related to downloading drivers from the company website (there are none I could find). I've tried manually selecting the sys and inf files through device manager, but this didn't seem to work. Possible I am doing this step wrong though.

Comment: Assuming this is Windows?  What version?

Comment: Windows 10. Knew I forgot to include something.

Comment: Your USB extender isn't working correctly. There is nothing you can do except not using it. This isn't about drivers. The extender isn't representing the device correctly.

Comment: @DanielB That's what I was afraid of. Was hoping because the other devices were working correctly that maybe there was something I could do to salvage this connection without having to purchase new things. Thank you for the insight.